# Calculating the number of weights in Convolutional Neural Network using Parameter Sharing

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

While reading a book [Machine Learning: a Probabilistic Perspective by Murphy](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/MLbook/) and [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16650/Neural-Network-for-Recognition-of-Handwritten-Digi) by Mike O'Neill I have encountered some calculations about the number of weights in Convolutional Neural Network which I want to understand. The architecture of the network is like this:

[image]

And this is the explanation from the above article:

> Layer #2 is also a convolutional layer, but with 50 feature maps. Each
>   feature map is 5x5, and each unit in the feature maps is a 5x5
>   convolutional kernel of corresponding areas of all 6 of the feature
>   maps of the previous layers, each of which is a 13x13 feature map.
>   There are therefore 5x5x50 = 1250 neurons in Layer #2, (5x5+1)x6x50 =
>   7800 weights, and 1250x26 = 32500 connections.

The calculation of the number of weights, **(5x5+1)x6x50 = 7800**, seems strange for me. Shouldn't be the actual calculation like this:
**(5x5x6+1)x50 = 7550** according to the parameter sharing explained [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/).

My argument is as follows:
We have 50 filters of size 5x5x6 and 1 bias for each filter, hence the total number of weights is (5x5x6+1)x50=7550. And this is Pytorch code which verifies this:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

model = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=6, out_channels=50, kernel_size=5, stride=2)
params_count = sum(param.numel() for param in model.parameters() if param.requires_grad)
print(params_count) # 7550
```

Can anyone explain this and which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

My calculations:

Layer-1 depth is 6, kernel : 5*5
Layer-2 depth is 50 , kernel : 5*5

Total number of neurons #Layer-2 : 5*5*50  = 1250

Total number of weights would be: 5*5*50*6 = 7500

Finally,  bias for #Layer-2 = 50 (depth is 50)

I agree with you : Total weights must be 7550.